# Unix Crontab Jobs

Tags: unix

I have a doubt in crontab, where the output of the cron job is stored when the output is 
not redirected.

Say for example: 
I have scheduled a cron job in the crontab file like

- - - - - pwd > /home/user/test.txt

The output of the pwd command is stored in the file /home/user/test.txt

When I am not redirecting the output where it will go?

- - - - - pwd

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

It should arrive in the mbox (mail) of the user.

Comment: @DUlac no I cant find any mbox related to that.

Comment: That's what it does, anyway.  Maybe your mail routing is broken.  Check the mail logs, mail queues, etc?  If your system is able to send mail to the outside, maybe set `MAILTO` to an address you are monitoring, in the Crontab file (provided you are using a Cron which supports this, but I guess most do).

Comment: Also maybe look for a file `dead.letter` in your home directory.